# когда правильно писать в предложении проведенных или произведенных

Tags: словообразование

когда  правильно писать  в предложении  проведенных или произведенных

Comment: зависит от предложения

Answer (score 3):

И то и другое правильно писать тогда, когда это сочетается с содержанием раскрываемых в предложении действий. В частности, нужно обращать внимание на сочетаемость причастия с существительным. Мероприятия *проводят*, действия и продукты *производят* и т. д. - нельзя всё охватить надёжным в использовании правилом.

> В результате проведённых разыскных мероприятий найдены гильзы от
>   выстрелов, произведённых преступником впервые после 10 лет,
>   проведённых им в тюрьме.

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря**

**ПРОВЕСТИ** 7. что. **Осуществить, произвести, выполнить** (какие-л. действия, работу). П. репетицию. П. заседание. Хорошо п. урок. П. соревнования. П. уборку урожая.

**ПРОИЗВЕСТИ**, св. 1. что. **Сделать, совершить; провести.** П. выстрел. П. вычисление. П. ремонт. **П. обыск.** П. расчёт кого-л. 2. что. **Создать материальные блага,** выпустить, изготовить продукцию.

В большинстве случаев слова "провести, проведенный" действительно относятся к **плановым мероприятиям**, которые осуществляют, **"проводят в жизнь"**. **Производят любые действия, имеющие результат**.

Интересно, что для существительных **"смотр и обыск" могут использоваться оба глагола:**

При таких условиях ни один адмирал доселе **не производил** смотра своей эскадре. Последний смотр, **произведенный** Верховным Правителем, был смотр новой добровольческой части. **Проведенный** смотр показал хорошее состояние и работоспособность всех аварийных бригад.

Сейчас сотрудники налоговой службы **проводят** обыск в офисном центре.
Судья может признать  **произведенный** обыск незаконным.

Comment: Думаю, что в случае обыска предпочтительно такое разграничение: "проводит" (= организует "произведение" обыска) его либо ведомство, либо руководитель сотрудников, которые его _непосредственно_ "производят", выполняя нужные для этого действия.

Comment: А по-моему, здесь эти слова являются практически синонимами. Например, из одной адвокатской статьи: В-четвертых, обыск и выемка должны производиться в присутствии двух понятых (ст. 169 УПК РСФСР). В-пятых, о проведенном обыске и выемке должен быть составлен протокол с соблюдением требований ст. 176 УПК .РСФСР.